# xamarin.ios how to make a nsobject[] as nsarray*

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, nsarray, nsobject

ios code:

```
NSArray *rows = @[@[@"C", @"Db", @"D", @"Eb", @"E", @"F", @"Gb", @"G", @"Ab", @"A", @"Bb", @"B"],
                  @[@"Major", @"Minor", @"Dorian", @"Spanish Gypsy"]];
```

In xamarin.ios ,how to make the nsobject[] as above code?

wrong:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString> x1=new NSMutableArray<NSString>(new NSString[]{ new NSString("北京"), new NSString("上海"), new NSString("广州"), new NSString("深圳") });
var area3 = new NSObject[] { x1 };
```

wrong:

```
var nsArray1 = NSArray<NSString>.FromObjects("北","上","广","深");
        var nsArray2 = NSArray<NSString>.FromObjects("北", "上", "广", "深");
var area2 = new NSObject[] { nsArray1, nsArray2 };
```

the nsobject[] parameter is the sharpie bind maked for me .In ios code's parameter is the nsarray*

Comment: to be frank ....... I did't understand ur issue.. can u explain ? more

Comment: hi @NAVEENKUMAR that is:I am a xamarin developer.and I start to convert a third library ActionSheetPicker to the c# library.After that, I start to use the library in my project.And In the ios demo,the nsarray* have 2 string array.But in my project the method let me fill the nsobject[] .so my question is how to make the nsobject[] as the array* which it have 2 string array